# How to fix "Found option without preceding group in config file my.ini at line: 1"

Tags: mysql

I used Open Server 5.2.2 to make rAthena (Ragnarok Online) works, but software shows this in MySQL Debugging Logs to me

> error: Found option without preceding group in config file:
>   d:\server\ragnarok\hectorro\03_openserver\modules\database\MySQL-5.6\my.ini
>   at line: 1
>       Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted

It's trying to run MySQL, but doesn't work.
I've tried to change unicode to ANSI, but as it said that it is a temporary file, it changed itself to `UTF-8-BOM` when I press start server.

See the comment below for `my.ini`

Answer (score 3):

100% Sure

> my.ini file

```
Open,
Save As..
Encoding >> Select ANSI
```

the file my.ini should be saved as ANSI encode,and [mysqld] group at the start of the file.

Comment: Thanks @Waruna Manjula